# Scala: why do I have to put extra parenthesis here?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

Are the parenthesis around the final tuple really needed? It doesn't compile without them and the compiler tries to add only the Sort("time") and complains that it expects a tuple instead.

```
val maxSortCounts: Map[Sort, Int] =
  sorts.map(s => s -> usedPredicates.map(pred => pred.signature.count(_ == s)).max)
    .toMap + ((Sort("time"), 1))
```

I've tried to reproduce this behaviour inside the REPL with a shorter example, but there it behaves as intended. The variable `sorts` is a `Seq[Sort]`.

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : <snip>.Sort
required: (<snip>.Sort, Int)
.toMap + (Sort("time"), 1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are needed. Otherwise the compiler will interpret the code as
`x.+(y, z)` instead of `x.+((y, z))`.

Instead, you can use ArrowAssoc again: `x + (y -> z)`. Notice, the parentheses are also needed because `+` and `-` have the same precedence (only the first sign of a method defines its precedence).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're needed. They make the expression a tuple. Parentheses surrounding a comma-separated list create tuple objects. For example, `(1, 2, 3)` is a 3-tuple of numbers.

`Map`'s `+` method accepts a pair - in other words a tuple of two elements. Map represents entries in the map as `(key,value)` tuples.